# Screen brightness ASUS UX303LA issues

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-core-i7

My screen brightness doesn't work, when I use the fn+ f5/6 key it only gets from really dark to little brighter in the lower part of the scale. So there is no leveling here or where it becomes brighter and brighter just two alternatives even though the scale moves.

Have downloaded two different VGA drivers from ASUS :

Versions: V10.18.15.4274.01 and
V10.18.13.5384

I think it has to do with the windows 10 upgrade, could be wrong :/

Comment: My Brothers desktop does the same thing im interested in this. +1 from me.

Comment: Is it limited by the Power Options (go to Control Panel, Power). Linux users appear to have some interesting ways around which may give an insight http://askubuntu.com/questions/656258/asus-ux303la-fn-brightness-keys-not-working